# Python Hive-PyHive Connection reset issue

Tags: python, hive, pyhive

I am able to connect to hive from Python using PyHive library. While fetching data from hive using PyHive I am facing issue `Connection reset by peer`.

After connection established I am fetching data from hive using PyHive from Python. Connection is getting successful but while fetching data from hive it runs for fore than 5 mins and then throws `connection reset by peer`.

```
from pyhive import 
hive conn = hive.Connection(host="host1", port="",auth="", database="",kerberos_service_name="") #successfully connection established 
cur = conn.cursor() cur.execute(query1) #(sometimes it works and some times it throws "Connection reset by peer" if query runs more than 5min)
```

Comment: Can you show us the [relevant code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) please?

Comment: from pyhive import hive

conn = hive.Connection(host="host1", port="",auth="", database="",kerberos_service_name="") -> successfully connection established
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(query1) -> (sometimes it works and some times it throws "Connection reset by peer" if query runs more than 5min)

Answer (score 0):

Not recognizing connection from server site can result into this error. Can you please try killing your python process using **pkill -9 pid**? Because if you trying to connect to hive using two python scripts at same time, it might result into not recognizing connection.